# Setting ORACLE_HOME to install cx_oracle

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I am trying to use python to connect to a remote oracle database and query it for a csv file and in doing so want to use the cx_oracle module. The oracle site recommends using pip to install the module however if you do not have an ORACLE_HOME path variable set then it give you the error

> raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate an Oracle software " \
>       distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate an Oracle software installation

Checking through the python setup file that comes in the tarball it seems as though the problem arises from not having an ORACLE_HOME variable set and can be remedied by setting a proper ORACLE_HOME. This is usually done automatically when you install any oracle software but I was wondering if there was a way around downloading unnecessary software.

Comment: I also am wary of just setting an environment variable that points to some directory for fear it might not be recognized as the true ORACLE_HOME if I need to install some oracle software later on.

Comment: Which OS are you using? See my gist here for some details: https://gist.github.com/jarshwah/3863378

Comment: You have to have the instantclient libraries installed - as that provides the headers needed to build cx_Oracle. It's all quite a pain.

Comment: I'm running Mac OS 10.10 which makes me wary to use an rpm file. So is the only way then to install those libraries?

Comment: You'll need to find the osx instantclient libs: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html but if I may suggest something - you might have an easier time running up a vagrant VM with centos if you're looking to do development with Oracle.